# Problemas al recorrer Array / Arreglo de PHP en tabla html

Tags: php, html, array

No consigo que se ponga cada elemento del arreglo en su lugar, este es el codigo y el resultado.
Son 2 archivos pero realmente el que cuenta es este.
Necesito ayuda, gracias.

Recorre el arreglo sin probelmas pero necesito situar los valores del array 1 debajo de Codigo y los del array 2 debajo de Unidades.

```
<table class="table table-responsive-md">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Codigo </th>
            <th> Unidades </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <?php 
                require_once('creacion_archivos.php');
            
                //Convierto los strings en arrays sin espacios
                $array_mitad_1 = explode("\n", $allData_mitad_1);
                $array_mitad_2 = explode("\n", $allData_mitad_2);
                //Los convierto a string solo con ';'
                $array_1_str = implode(";", $array_mitad_1);
                $array_2_str = implode(";", $array_mitad_2);
                //Estos string los paso a array separandolos por ';'
                $array_1 = explode(";", $array_1_str);
                $array_2 = explode(";", $array_2_str);

                echo gettype($array_1);
                echo '<br/>';
                print_r($array_1);
                echo '<br/>';

                $n_numero = count($array_1) -1;
                echo $n_numero;
                echo '<br/>';
                

                for( $i=0; $i<$n_numero; $i+=2 ){
                    // echo "$array_1[$i] <br/>";
                    echo "<td> $array_1[$i] </td>";
                    echo "<td> $array_2[$i] </td>";
                }

            ?>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
```

Comment: No acabo de entender lo que haces realizando un implode con ; y luego un explode con ;. Podrías explicar mejor qué es lo que tienes en creacion_archivos.php y cómo están estructurados los strings allData_mitad_1 y allData_mitad_2?

Comment: Si, tengo que hacer una 2 tablas donde Codigo pertenece a los numeros de 6 digitos y donde en Unidades tienen que ir los nuemros de 2 o 1 digitos.  Por eso mismo primero el string con los datos le quito el espacidado para luego al ginal tener un array con solo ; lo cual me deberia de ser mas facil a la hora de manipularlo, pero no consigo poner cada cosa en su lugar.

Answer (score 0):

No se si realmente he entendido lo que quieres hacer, pero para crear la tabla con dos columnas, tienes que añadir el `tr` dentro del bucle.

```
<table class="table table-responsive-md">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Codigo </th>
            <th> Unidades </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <?php 
                require_once('creacion_archivos.php');
            
                $array_1 = explode("\n", $allData_mitad_1);
                $array_2 = explode("\n", $allData_mitad_2);
                
                for( $i=0; $i<count($array_1); $i++ ){
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td> $array_1[$i] </td>";
                    echo "<td> $array_2[$i] </td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }

            ?>
    </tbody>
</table>[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
```

Comment: Si muchas gracias, ya lo solucioné, puse lo de <tr> pero aun asi no podia poner los datos en la segunda columna, en la de Unidades, ya que no podía hacerlo con el bucle for, despues de buscar mucha infrmacion lo que hice fue cambiar mi array en con array_chunk($array_1, 2), asi con un foreach lo he solucionado a la perfeccion, muchas gracias por ti tiempo.